# How to limit return in a jQuery for each loop?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, loops, foreach

I am using jQuery to pull data from an API, and I cannot limit the results through a query paramter.

My code is this -

```
$.ajax({
    method: 'GET',
    url: url
}).done(function (data, status, xhr) {
    $.each(data, function (index, value) {
        $("div").append(
            `html markup`
        )
    });
});
```

I want to break the loop once it returns 3 results.

I tried adding a counter inside the loop like this -

```
let i = 0;
$.ajax({
    method: 'GET',
    url: url
}).done(function (data, status, xhr) {
    $.each(data, function (index, value) {
        if ( i === 3 ) return false
        $("div").append(
            `html markup`
        )
    });
});
```

but with that conditional it does not return any results

Comment: `if ( index === 3 ) return false`

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Array#slice` to get only the first three elements.

```js
$.each(data.slice(0, 3), (index, value) => {

});
```